# Bash - Search based on timestamp in milliseconds

Tags: bash, hadoop, awk, hadoop2

I am searching all the Hadoop completed(100s of) jobs between a time interval. This time interval is in milliseconds.

Following is the format:

```
JobId      State           StartTime      UserName           Queue      Priority       UsedContainers  RsvdContainers      UsedMem         RsvdMem        NeededMem                 AM info

job_xxxxxxx  SUCCEEDED       1458844667431    default    default          NORMAL                  N/A             N/A          N/A           N/A        N/A             http://xxxxxxxx:8088/proxy/application_xxxxxxxxxx/jobhistory/job/job_xxxxxxxx
job_xxxxxxx  SUCCEEDED       1459449718363    default    default         NORMAL                  N/A             N/A        N/A             N/A              N/A        http://xxxxxx.xxxxx.com:8088/proxy/application_xxxxxxxxx/jobhistory/job/job_xxxxx
```

Following is my format:

```
STARTTIME="Tue Apr 12 10:24:29 EDT 2016"
ENDTIME="Tue Apr 12 15:24:29 EDT 2016"

CONVERTTIME_1=`date --date="$STARTTIME" +%s%3N`
CONVERTTIME_2=`date --date="$ENDTIME" +%s%3N`

echo $CONVERTTIME_1, $CONVERTTIME_2

mapred job -list all | sed -n '/$CONVERTTIME_1/,/$CONVERTTIME_2/p' > out
```

Output: all the jobs like above within that `timerange`.

Can anyone please help how to get these?

OUTPUT OF mapred job -list all

mapred job -list all

```
 job_1457613852865_5163  SUCCEEDED       1459199337140    zzzzzzzzzz    uuuuuuuu_critical          NORMAL                  N/A             N/A      N/A           N/A        N/A      http://xxxxx254.yyyyyy.com:8088/proxy/application_1457613852865_5163/jobhistory/job/job_1457613852865_5163

 job_1457613852865_4633  SUCCEEDED       1458992402216       zzzyyyy    yyyyyy_default       NORMAL                  N/A             N/A      N/A             N/A              N/A      http://xxxxx254.yyyyyy.com:8088/proxy/application_1457613852865_4633/jobhistory/job/job_1457613852865_4633

 job_1457613852865_4821  SUCCEEDED       1459078845580       zzzyyyy    yyyyyy_default       NORMAL                  N/A             N/A      N/A             N/A              N/A      http://xxxxx254.yyyyyy.com:8088/proxy/application_1457613852865_4821/jobhistory/job/job_1457613852865_4821

 job_1457613852865_0322  SUCCEEDED       1457717313217        zzzddd    uuuuuuuu_critical          NORMAL                  N/A             N/A      N/A           N/A        N/A      http://xxxxx254.yyyyyy.com:8088/proxy/application_1457613852865_0322/jobhistory/job/job_1457613852865_0322

 job_1457613852865_5304  SUCCEEDED       1459254375921       zzzyyyy    yyyyyy_default       NORMAL                  N/A             N/A      N/A             N/A              N/A      http://xxxxx254.yyyyyy.com:8088/proxy/application_1457613852865_5304/jobhistory/job/job_1457613852865_5304

 job_1457613852865_8744  SUCCEEDED       1460195126188       zzzyyyy    yyyyyy_default       NORMAL                  N/A             N/A      N/A             N/A              N/A      http://xxxxx254.yyyyyy.com:8088/proxy/application_1457613852865_8744/jobhistory/job/job_1457613852865_8744

 job_1457613852865_3384  SUCCEEDED       1458649020794       zzzyyyy    yyyyyy_default       NORMAL                  N/A             N/A      N/A             N/A              N/A      http://xxxxx254.yyyyyy.com:8088/proxy/application_1457613852865_3384/jobhistory/job/job_1457613852865_3384

 job_1457613852865_9038  SUCCEEDED       1460291694279       zzzyyyy    yyyyyy_default       NORMAL                  N/A             N/A      N/A             N/A              N/A      http://xxxxx254.yyyyyy.com:8088/proxy/application_1457613852865_9038/jobhistory/job/job_1457613852865_9038

 job_1457613852865_8487  SUCCEEDED       1460115319590       zzzyyyy    yyyyyy_default       NORMAL                  N/A             N/A      N/A             N/A              N/A      http://xxxxx254.yyyyyy.com:8088/proxy/application_1457613852865_8487/jobhistory/job/job_1457613852865_8487

 job_1457613852865_8321  SUCCEEDED       1460038991587        dddyyy    uuuuuuuu_critical          NORMAL                  N/A             N/A      N/A           N/A        N/A      http://xxxxx254.yyyyyy.com:8088/proxy/application_1457613852865_8321/jobhistory/job/job_1457613852865_8321

 job_1457613852865_4661  SUCCEEDED       1458994901619       zzzyyyy    yyyyyy_default       NORMAL                  N/A             N/A      N/A             N/A              N/A      http://xxxxx254.yyyyyy.com:8088/proxy/application_1457613852865_4661/jobhistory/job/job_1457613852865_4661

 job_1457613852865_1975  SUCCEEDED       1458216683800       zzzyyyy    yyyyyy_default       NORMAL                  N/A             N/A      N/A             N/A              N/A      http://xxxxx254.yyyyyy.com:8088/proxy/application_1457613852865_1975/jobhistory/job/job_1457613852865_1975
```

I used this:

```
#!/bin/bash


STARTTIME="Tue Apr 12 10:13:01 EDT 2016"
ENDTIME="Tue Apr 12 10:13:59 EDT 2016"

start=$(date -d "$STARTTIME" '+%s%3N')
end=$(date -d "$ENDTIME" '+%s%3N')

echo "start=$start :: end=$end"

mapred job -list all | awk -v start="$start" -v end="$end" '$3>=start && $3<=end'
```

Got one extra job:

```
job_1457613852865_9785  SUCCEEDED       1460470436726       yyyyyyyyyy    nnnnnnnnnn       NORMAL                  N/A             N/A      N/A             N/A              N/A      http://888888.xxxxxxxxxx.com:8088/proxy/application_1457613852865_9785/jobhistory/job/job_1457613852865_9785
```

Comment: What is your search pattern and what is expected output?

Comment: #!/bin/bash

#STARTTIME="12-Apr-2016 10:00:00.012"
#ENDTIME="12-Apr-2016 11:00:00.012"

STARTTIME="Tue Apr 12 10:24:29 EDT 2016"
ENDTIME="Tue Apr 12 15:24:29 EDT 2016"

CONVERTTIME_1=`date --date="$STARTTIME" +%s%3N`
CONVERTTIME_2=`date --date="$ENDTIME" +%s%3N`

echo $CONVERTTIME_1, $CONVERTTIME_2

mapred job -list all | sed -n '/$CONVERTTIME_1/,/$CONVERTTIME_2/p' > out


output: all the jobs like above within that timerange.

Comment: Update the question with this code.

Comment: Why is your script not using `STARTTIME` or `ENDTIME`?

Comment: mapred job -list all - command list all the jobs in the below format:

    job_xxxxxxx  SUCCEEDED       1458844667431    default    default              NORMAL                  N/A             N/A       N/A           N/A        N/A          http://xxxxxxxx:8088/proxy/application_xxxxxxxxxx/jobhistory/job/job_xxxxxxxx

The search pattern contains the time in the format defined in STARTTIME. I am converting this start/end time into the same format. That's why I can't use the STARTTIME directly

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how to represent the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your dates into millisec value and then use awk to filter your data:

```
STARTTIME="Tue Apr 12 10:24:29 EDT 2016"
ENDTIME="Tue Apr 12 15:24:29 EDT 2016"

start=$(date -d "$STARTTIME" '+%s%3N')
end=$(date -d "$ENDTIME" '+%s%3N')"

echo "start=$start :: end=$end"
mapred job -list all | awk -v start="$start" -v end="$end" '$3>=start && $3<=end'
```

Comment: Anubhava

Can you be a bit more specific:

1. mapred job -list all -> this command gives the output of all the jobs.
2. I am already converting my time into milliseconds.
3. What should I run on mapred command defined in step 1 to filter the data?

Comment: I want to add the code, can you tell me how to indent it? BTW, your code didn't work

Comment: # ./test.sh 
    1460471069000, 1460489069000 
 
 
    cat test.sh 
 
    #!/bin/bash 

    STARTTIME="Tue Apr 12 10:24:29 EDT 2016" 
    ENDTIME="Tue Apr 12 15:24:29 EDT 2016" 
 
    start=$(date -d "$STARTTIME" '+%s%3N') 
    end=$(date -d "$ENDTIME" '+%s%3N') 
 
    echo $start, $end 
 
    mapred job -list all | awk -v start="$start" -v end="$end" '$1>=start && $1<=end'

Comment: It is working but I need some time to verify your answer, just to ask some intermediate help if possible, can we format the milliseconds data coming from mapred command into STARTTIME format? BTW this time there is certainly some answer and looks like it is BINGO!!!

Comment: I got one extra job, I have updated the question. sure, I will mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Absolutely agreed..no extra thing at all.. I updated the question saying that I am getting an extra job. Please check the last update. Apologies but seems there was a miss from your side.

Comment: Clarify how is `1460470436726` line an extra job? If you convert to date it will come as `Tue Apr 12 10:13:57 EDT 2016` which falls between `start` and `end` .